# Iterate through an array and remove all values that contain a specific word

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
suggestions = [ "the dog", 
                "the cat", 
                "the boat",
                "boat engine",
                "boat motor",
                "motor oil"
              ];
```

How can I iterate through the array and remove all the entries that contain a specific word?

For example, removing all entires that contain the word "the", so the array becomes:

```
[ "boat engine",
  "boat motor",
  "motor oil"
];
```

Comment: Loop backwards, and use a regex to look for the word, then `splice` the item if it matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this setup:

```
var suggestions = [
    "the dog",
    "the cat",
    "he went then",
    "boat engine",
    "another either thing",
    "some string the whatever"
];

function filterWord(arr, filter) {
    var i = arr.length, cur,
        re = new RegExp("\\b" + filter + "\\b");
    while (i--) {
        cur = arr[i];
        if (re.test(cur)) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}

filterWord(suggestions, "the");
console.log(suggestions);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Kacju/

It loops backward, correctly checking for the word to look for (by using the `\b` identifier as a word boundary), and removes any matches.

If you want to generate a new array containing the matches, loop normally and just `push` any non-matches to the new array. You could use this:

```
var suggestions = [
    "the dog",
    "the cat",
    "he went then",
    "boat engine",
    "another either thing",
    "some string the whatever"
];

function filterWord(arr, filter) {
    var i, j, cur, ret = [],
        re = new RegExp("\\b" + filter + "\\b");
    for (i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
        cur = arr[i];
        if (!re.test(cur)) {
            ret.push(cur);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

var newSuggestions = filterWord(suggestions, "the");
console.log(newSuggestions);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Kacju/1/

Answer (score 3):

It's probably easier to create a new array:

```
var correct = [],
    len = suggestions.length,
    i = 0,
    val;

for (; i < len; ++i) {
    val = suggestions[i];
    if (val.indexOf('the') === -1) {
        correct.push(val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regex

```
var suggestions = [ "the dog", 
                "the cat", 
                "the boat",
                "boat engine",
                "boat motor",
                "motor oil"
              ];
var filtered = [],
    len = suggestions.length,
    val,
    checkCondition = /\bthe\b/;

for (var i =0; i < len; ++i) {
    val = suggestions[i];
    if (!checkCondition.test(val)) {
        filtered.push(val);
    }
}
```

**[check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/yhw54/)**

Answer (score -2):

Using the power of ECMAScript5 :

```
suggestions.reduce (
  function (r, s) {!(/\bthe\b/.test (s)) && r.push (s); return r; }, []);
```